# jQuery Countdown has incorrect date

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm working with the countdown on this page http://chips.be-different.co.uk/

The countdown code (to 18th February) is:

```
 $('#countdown').countdown({until: new Date(2013, 02, 18), format: 'DHMS', labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Mins', 'Secs'], labels1: ['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Min', 'Sec'], expiryText: '', layout: '<div class="section"><div class="value">{dnn}</div><div class="label">{dl}</div></div><div class="section no-space"><div class="value">:</div></div><div class="section"><div class="value">{hnn}</div><div class="label">{hl}</div></div><div class="section no-space"><div class="value">:</div></div><div class="section"><div class="value">{mnn}</div><div class="label">{ml}</div></div><div class="section no-space"><div class="value">:</div></div><div class="section"><div class="value">{snn}</div><div class="label">{sl}</div></div>'});
```

yet it shows 68 days countdown, which is definitely not right!

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date(2013, 2, 18)` is Mon Mar 18 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100.

Months start counting in javascript at `0`, so use `new Date(2013, 1, 18)` if you want february 18th :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that months in `Date` are 0 based, 0 = January. So it's correct